# Reading Chinese text from a file and printing it to the shell

Tags: python, utf-8, foreign-keys, decode, encode

I'm trying to make a program which reads lines Chinese characters from a .txt file and prints them to the Python shell (IDLE?).

The problem I'm having is trying to encode and decode the characters in utf-8 to the point where they will actually print in Chinese.

So far I have this:

```
  file_name = input("Enter the core name of the text you wish to analyze:")+'.txt'

  file = open(file_name, encoding="utf8")

  file = file.read().decode('utf-8').split()

  print(file)
```

Every time I run the code, however, I keep getting prompted with this error.

```
    file = file.read().decode('utf-8').split()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Now, I'm not entirely sure what this means since I'm new to the programming language, so I was wondering if I could get some tips from you guys. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error message, I suspect the output of `.read()` is a string already (more precisely, unicode char points if you are using `Python 3`).

Did you try it without the `.decode()` call?

---

For better file handling use the `with` context, as that assures that your file will be closed correctly after exiting the block.
Also, you can iterate over the lines in the file using a `for line in f` statement.

```
file_name = input("Enter the core name of the text you wish to analyze:")

with open(file_name + '.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()   # removes new lines or spaces at the start/end
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you read a file opened this way in Python 3:

file = open(file_name, encoding="utf8")

You are telling it that the file is encoded in UTF-8 and Python will *automatically* decode it.  `file.read()` is already a Unicode string (the `str` type in Python 3), so you can 't decode it again.  Just do the following (and don't overwrite `file`...that's your file handle):

```
data = file.read().split()
```